# Angular SSR ERROR ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I try to create a new project and add SSR to it and it works fine.

But when I try to add SSR to an existing project this error occurs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal';
  
  or 

// app.browser
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'isBrowser', useValue: true }
  ]
})

  
   
then inject from constructor

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject('isBrowser') private isBrowser: boolean)
  ngOnInit() { 
    // example usage, this could be anywhere in this Component of course
    if (this.isBrowser) { 
      alert('we're in the browser!');
    }
}


<ng-container *ngIf="isBrowser">
   <!-- mqttws31-component -->
   <mqttws31-component></mqttws31-component> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, still I got an error swiper is not defined.

Comment: most likely you're using Swiper in your project which doesn't care about platform (server in this case). You have to not execute any Swiper's logic when on server, using technique similar to @Kunjan already proposed.